# How to see if a user has clicked on two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a selection menu. I want the user to be able to select two different options and have something displayed depending on what they have selected. Right now, I am just using images to represent the selections. I am wondering if there is a way to see if a user has selected/clicked two of the images consecutively. After the user has clicked two pictures, I want them to be redirected to another page and have something displayed.

```
/*clicked on certain two images*/(function(){
    document.location.href="#page";
    $('option').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class to mark selection and after each click, check to see if two are selected:

```
$('img').click( function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    if($('img.selected').length == 2) {
        alert("Two images selected!");
        // Or redirect to new page, etc.
    }
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/G9NXA/

This is, of course, a generic solution.  You probably don't want to use `img` as your selector, but some other class that defines your selectable images.

If you want to make sure the clicks/selections are consecutive clicks, simply clear the selection if the user clicks anywhere else:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G9NXA/1/

And if you meant spatially consecutive, rather than temporally consecutive, here is another example:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G9NXA/2/

Comment: Perfect answer. I'm deleting mine.

Comment: You just beat me to the punch :P

Comment: though you should probably do `$('.selected').length` to allow mixing and matching of tag types. To see if specifically `$('#img1')` and `$('#img2')` are selected, then the if condition becomes `if($('#img1').hasClass('selected') && $('#img2').hasClass('selected'))`

Comment: @HansZ: Yes, although I would still use a class.  That way, you could have multiple selection menus on a page.  `$('.menu1.selected').length`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This is a really nice method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store javascript state, you could try adding a marker class to the selected images on click and count how many are found then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest method I came up with:

```
var tracker = [];

$('*').click(
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        var lastEl = tracker.length ? tracker.pop() : '',
            tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        tracker.push(tag);
        if (tag == lastEl) {
            doSomething();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XfHFn/).

This applies a click handler to *all* elements, though (and prevents propagation/bubbling of the event, so you should be more specific in your selector than I have here); it also stores the tag-name each clicked-element in an array and then matches the tag-name of the currently-clicked element with the tag-name of the previously-clicked item.

If the two are the same, then the `if` evaluation returns `true` and the `doSomething()` is executed; otherwise the click-handler returns `false`, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

This depends. If the images are sibling nodes you could check .prev() and .next(). You the image on click with a class like 'imageClicked'. Then check if the .prev() or .next() also has that class.

```
$('img').click( function() {
    var clickedImg = $(this);

    clickedImg.toggleClass('imageClicked');

    if(clickedImg.hasClass('imageClicked')) {
        if(clickedImg.prev().hasClass('imageClicked') ||
        clickedImg.next().hasClass('imageClicked'))
            alert('Siblings Selected!');
    }
});
```